# Error trying to convert simple convolutional model to CoreML

Tags: pytorch, coreml, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to convert a simple GAN generator (from ClusterGAN):

```
self.name = 'generator'
self.latent_dim = latent_dim
self.n_c = n_c
self.x_shape = x_shape
self.ishape = (128, 7, 7)
self.iels = int(np.prod(self.ishape))
self.verbose = verbose

self.model = nn.Sequential(
    # Fully connected layers
    torch.nn.Linear(self.latent_dim + self.n_c, 1024),
    nn.BatchNorm1d(1024),
    nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
    torch.nn.Linear(1024, self.iels),
    nn.BatchNorm1d(self.iels),
    nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),

    # Reshape to 128 x (7x7)
    Reshape(self.ishape),

    # Upconvolution layers
    nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True),
    nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
    nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),

    nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 1, 4, stride=2, padding=1, bias=True),
    nn.Sigmoid()
)
```

But onnx-coreml fails with `Error while converting op of type: BatchNormalization. Error message: provided number axes 2 not supported`

I thought it was the BatchNorm2d, so I tried reshaping and applying BatchNorm1d, but I get the same error. Any thoughts? I'm very surprised that I'm having problems converting such a simple model, so I'm assuming that I must be missing something obvious.

I'm targeting iOS 13 and using Opset v10 for the onnx conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Core ML does not have 1-dimensional batch norm. The tensor must have at least rank 3.

If you want to convert this model, you should fold the batch norm weights into those of the preceding layer and remove the batch norm layer. (I don't think PyTorch has a way to automatically do this for you.)

Comment: Yes, stepping through this in more detail I realized that the `BatchNorm1d` is where the error initially occurs. Removing those I get `axes -1 not supported` error from the `BatchNorm2d`. What you're suggesting sounds reasonable, though I have to confess I have no idea how I'd go about doing that. Do you mean editing the trained model somehow, or could this be done in PyTorch?

Comment: BatchNorm is a linear transformation and so is Linear (obviously). If you write out the math, you can combine the weights from the batchnorm layer with the weights and bias of the Linear layer. And then remove the batchnorm layer from the PyTorch model. The math isn't really that hard but I don't have time right now to write it all out.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've actually got the model running nicely on iOS using LibTorch, so I'll go with that for now.